# Not all emails are coming into Thunderbird from Gmail

Tags: email

Can anyone offer some insight as to why only some of my emails are being pulled into Thunderbird from Gmail?  I noticed that my TBird doesn't have a junk mail folder set up in it - could this be the problem?  The mail that's missing is standard inbox stuff in Gmail...

Comment: Is this really related to Ubuntu only?

Comment: Well, isn't it possible that some modification in the version distributed by Canonical may be responsible for TBird's behavior?

Comment: Are you saying this could be Thunderbird problem?